# SwiftUI - Only one object property true in Array

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to model my data with the **Model, View, Viewmodel framework.**

In my project, i have a **Model called Category** which is a class. 
Each Category have and id, a name and a var isActive of type bool.

I'm currently displaying a Hstack ScrollView with all my categories as buttons.
[Click here to visually see my view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gout5.jpg)

I added a **OnTapGesture on each category button** to change the size of the button when tapped.
My problem is that **i can have more than one category selected at the same time**.

I'm wondering **what's the best way to structure my data so that i can only select one category**.

Should i delete the isActive variable on my Category Model ? 
What should i try next ?

Category Model -

```
Category Model
struct Category: Identifiable {

    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var category: categories
    var isActive: Bool

}

/// Represent all possible categories cases
enum categories: String, CaseIterable {
    case love = "❤️"
    case family = "‍‍‍"
    case urgent = ""
    case sex = ""
    case funny = ""
    case school = ""
    case sport = ""
}

#if DEBUG
let categoryTest = [
    Category(category: .love, isActive: false),
    Category(category: .family, isActive: false),
    Category(category: .urgent, isActive: false),
    Category(category: .sex, isActive: false),
    Category(category: .funny, isActive: false),
    Category(category: .school, isActive: false),
    Category(category: .sport, isActive: false)
]
#endif
```

CategoriesView -

```
//Categories View - Looping all categories & CategoryView - The way i display each category and add the Tap Gesture
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine

struct CategoriesView: View {

    @ObservedObject var categoriesVM = CategoriesViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {

            Text("Catégories")
                .font(.title).bold()
                .offset(y: 20)

            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(categoriesVM.categoryViewModel) { categoryVM in
                        CategoryView(categoryVM: categoryVM)
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.leading, 15)
    }
}

struct CategoriesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CategoriesView()
    }
}


struct CategoryView: View {
    @ObservedObject var categoryVM: CategoryViewModel

    var onComit: (Category) -> (Void) = { _ in }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {

            Text(categoryVM.category.category.rawValue)
                .font(.system(size: self.categoryVM.category.isActive ? 26 : 22, weight: .bold))
            .frame(
                width: self.categoryVM.category.isActive ? 80 : 60,
                height: self.categoryVM.category.isActive ? 80 : 60
            )
            .background(Color.white)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.1), radius: 10, x: 10, y: 10)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.categoryVM.category.isActive.toggle()
                print("Tapped, state: \(self.categoryVM.category.isActive)")
            }

        }
        .frame(height: 130)
    }
}
```

Category View Model -

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine

class CategoryViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {

    @Published var category: Category
    var id: String = ""
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
//    @Published var categoryIcon = ""

    init(category: Category) {
        self.category = category

        $category // (7)
        .map { $0.id }
        .assign(to: \.id, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)

}

}
```

Categories View Model -

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine

class CategoriesViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {

    @Published var categoryViewModel = [CategoryViewModel]()

    private var cancellables =  Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        self.categoryViewModel = categoryTest.map { category in
            CategoryViewModel(category: category)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my first thought is remove isActive from Category and create a `@State var currentCategory: UUID` in `CategoriesView`:

```
struct CategoriesView: View {

    @ObservedObject var categoriesVM = CategoriesViewModel()
    @State var currentCategory: UUID = UUID()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {

            Text("Catégories")
                .font(.title).bold()
                .offset(y: 20)

            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(categoriesVM.categoryViewModel) { categoryVM in
                        CategoryView(categoryVM: categoryVM, currentCategory: $currentCategory)
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.leading, 15)
    }
}
```

and then check and assign currentCategory in your CategoryView:

```
struct CategoryView: View {
    @ObservedObject var categoryVM: CategoryViewModel
    @Binding var currentCategory

    var onComit: (Category) -> (Void) = { _ in }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {

            Text(categoryVM.category.category.rawValue)
                .font(.system(size: isCurrentCategory() ? 26 : 22, weight: .bold))
            .frame(
                width: isCurrentCategory() ? 80 : 60,
                height: isCurrentCategory() ? 80 : 60
            )
            .background(Color.white)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.1), radius: 10, x: 10, y: 10)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.currentCategory = self.categoryVM.category.id
            }

        }
        .frame(height: 130)
    }

    private func isCurrentCategory() -> Bool {
      return categoryVM.category.id == currentCategory
    }
}
```

I didnt check if my code compiles or not, but this way you cant have more than one active category.